# How to draw dotted equipotential lines in the pst-electricfield package?

Tags: pstricks, pst-electricfield

I would like the psequipotential lines to be dotted or dashed (preferably dashed) and the pselectricfield lines to be solid. I tried doing this but it does not become dashed:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psscalebox{0.8}{
\psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -1 0][1 1 0]},linecolor=black]
\psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -1 0][1 1 0]},linecolor=black,linestyle=dashed](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)}
\end{pspicture*}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the picture that is rendered:

[image]

I would like the circular lines that form loops and made from very small dots to be dashed. The electric field lines which are arrows are find it is the equipotential lines I would like to be dashed. How do I do this?

Comment: Weird. Not even the usual trick of putting `\psset{linestyle=dashed}` before the command seems to work. (If you have gnuplot installed, you can also do implict plots with pgfplots, I think.)

Comment: If you look closely you can see that the equipotential lines are made of a lot of small dots rather than lines, so I think that may be the reason, but I am not entirely sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the .pro and .tex version from

http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/dvips/pst-electricfield/

http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pst-electricfield/

the following works. For the equipotentiallines is no dash possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psscalebox{0.8}{%
    \psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -1 0][1 1 0]},linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]
    \psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -1 0][1 1 0]},linecolor=blue](-4,-4)(4,4)}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the other set of lines, the blue ones to be dashed instead

Comment: Not possible, implicit defined functions are plotted dots and no lines or curves